# Getting error while adding custom style in android

Tags: android, android-styles

I have following the custom style in style folder

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="OurAppTheme" parent="AppTheme"/>


<!--Used-->
<style name="TextHeadingStyle" parent="OurAppTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/antic</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

But when i am setting items to style it give me error.

Here I have attached a screenshot of the error

[image]

Help me to get rid of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag `<resources` has wrong closing tag.

```
<resources>

</resources> <<---------------<< correct it
```

**Edit**

If this does not work. Try Invalidate Cache & Restart.

Comment: Can you run app?

Comment: i can't because at compile time i am getting this error

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Cache & Restart?

Comment: Let me try this one ,then i will get back to you.